# React native 0.71.3 cli.init(root, projectName); TypeError: cli.init is not a function

Tags: android, ios, react-native, typeerror, react-native-cli

**REACT NATIVE Version 0.71.3**

> AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:302
> cli.init(root, projectName);

```
      ^

TypeError: cli.init is not a function
    at run (C:\Users\katyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:302:7)
    at createProject (C:\Users\katyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:249:3)
    at init (C:\Users\katyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\katyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-cli\index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try to uninstall CLI globally**

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli
```

> then install CLI again globally

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g react-native
```

> This works properly with newer versions of react native if you face
> this problem